# Disable specific ServletContextListener to prevent startup on tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-webflux, servletcontextlistener

My project is using `spring boot` with `webflux`, `tomcat`.

I have a internal library class that is a `ServletContextListener`

```
@WebListener
public class DevIoServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Inject
    private DevIoInjector injector;

    public DevIoServletContextListener() {
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        this.injector.inject();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    }
}
```

This internal class throws an exception inside method `contextInitialized`:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.dev.lib.DevIoServletContextListener.contextInitialized(DevIoServletContextListener.java:33)
```

this class is not important for my development.. i would like ignore or disable this listener, is possible?

I don't make changes inside this listener because is an internal class from a library.

I will appreciate any help.

I tried add @ServletComponentScan("br.com.dev.bit.io") with my packages only inside main class, but not worked.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("br.com.dev.bit.io")
@ServletComponentScan("br.com.dev.bit.io")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `DevIoServletContextListener` contained in a JAR file or in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory? The servlet container should scan the latter for annotations, but not the former.

Comment: Priotr P. Karwasz is a JAVA file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to disable a listener annotated with `@WebListener` in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder is to disable annotation scanning altogether through the `metadata-complete` attribute in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` descriptor:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="true"
    version="4.0">
    ...
</web-app>
```

This will not disable `ServletContainerInitializer`s, therefore Spring Boot initialization will be unaffected.