# Force @Autowired spring boot and webFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, autowired, servletcontextlistener

My application use `spring boot` and `webflux` with `tomcat` embedded.

I use a 3rd library that contains some servlet listeners.

A listener property `injector` of `BagServletContextListener` returns null when the app is started.

```
@WebListener
public class BagServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Autowired
    private BagInjector injector;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        this.injector.inject();

    }
}
```

How can I force initialization of this component through `@bean` or other way?

a piece of my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Note: The packaging of app is a war.

The lack of initialization of this component cause null pointer exception in contextInitialized method.

`[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.devIo.ee.BagServletContextListener.contextInitialized(BagServletContextListener.java:33) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2391) at [internal classes]`

Comment: Since, according to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67881304/11748454), this class is deployed in `WEB-INF/classes`, Spring does not instantiate it, Tomcat does. Tomcat can only inject resources registered with JNDI (through the `@Inject` or `@Resource` annotations).

Comment: I don’t understand if i need create the WEBINF/classes. My project not contains this

Comment: You said that `BagServletContextListener` is a java file in your project: java files are compiled and copied to the `WEB-INF/classes` folder of your WAR file **and** are scanned for Servlet 3.0 annotations. On the other hand your Maven dependencies are copied into `WEB-INF/lib` and are **not** scanned for annotations. That is why Tomcat discovers your class and instantiates it, but is not able to inject a `BagInjector`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not told Spring Boot to scan your `BagServletContextListener` class. The `@WebListener` does not accomplish that.

Add `@ServletComponentScan` to your SpringBootApplication class to ensure the `BagInjector` is scanned - and Spring knows how to autowire it for you.

Like this:

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, the exception keeps happening because the injector is null :(

Comment: _"Scanning is only performed when using an embedded web server."_ @chewie: did you try running your application using the embedded server?

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz i use tomcat embedded server